# How to access sub item in json using Guide template language in this code?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json, gtl

I am using Guide template language to pull content from a remote url.

This works but takes the title from too high up in json structure:

```
{{.dataobject JsonVar type=variable source=@json maxrows=3}}
{{.data}}
{"target":"@json"}
{{/data}}
{{/dataobject}}

{{#each JsonVar}}
{{title}}
{{/each}}
```

(I need the each-function to be there since I have some functions there)
So since title is pulled from top item I need to get the title from the sub item, and that is the part that doesn't work:

```
{{.dataobject JSONVar type=variable maxRows = 1}}
{{.data}}
{ "target" : "@json" }
{{/data}}

{{.dataobject items type=nested maxRows = 3}}
{{.data}}
{ "target" : "JsonVar.items" }
{{/data}}

{{/dataobject}}
{{/dataobject}}

{{#each items}}
{{title}}
{{/each}}
```

But I keeep getting this error when I try the last version:

> The data source referenced by a Guide Each tag was not found. JobID: 0
>   SlotID: 0 DataSourceIDType: Unspecified DataSourceID: items Guide Tag:
>   {{#each items}} Tag Index: 2605

So how can I access items in a sub item and still use #each?

Comment: Can you post the XML?  Hard to help without it.

Comment: I solved it using TreatAsContent("{{items.title}}")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `datasource` instead of `dataobject` in the example you provided. Simply replace the four occurrences of `dataobject` with `datasource`, then move your two closing `{{/datasource}}` tags after the closing `{{/each}}` tag and that should work.